# Return the key if a value is found inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Having an object like:

```
var animals = { "dog": ["black", "red", "green"],
                 "cat": ["pink", "red", "white"],
                 "bird": ["green", "grey", "yellow"]};
```

I want to get back the name of the animal which has a certain color, for example for `"red"` I want to return an array containing `["dog", "cat"]`;
Tried to do it but I only get back Array(0) or Array(1)

```
function findColor(animals, color) {

  var result = [];
  if (Object.values(animals).indexOf(color) > -1) {
    result.push(color);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(findColor(animals, "red"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simply use `Object.keys` and `filter`

```js
var animals = {
  "dog": ["black", "red", "green"],
  "cat": ["pink", "red", "white"],
  "bird": ["green", "grey", "yellow"]
};

function findColor(animals, color) {
  return Object.keys(animals).filter(key=>animals[key].includes(color))
}

console.log(findColor(animals, 'red'));
```

---

> Why my code is not working ?

indexOf uses strict comparision, Object.values(animals) returns an 2d array and you're trying to match it with a string value, what you need to do it loop over keys and use indexOf on subarray on 2d array

```js
var animals = {"dog": ["black", "red", "green"],"cat": ["pink", "red", "white"],"bird": ["green", "grey", "yellow"]};

function findColor(animals, color) {
  var result = [];
  Object.keys(animals).forEach(v => {
    if (animals[v].indexOf(color) > -1) {
      result.push(v)
    }
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(findColor(animals, "red"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` and then iterate the array and then check based on condition :

```js
var animals = { "dog": ["black", "red", "green"],
                 "cat": ["pink", "red", "white"],
                 "bird": ["green", "grey", "yellow"]};

function findColor(animals, color) {
  let result = []
   Object.keys(animals).forEach(key=>{
     if(animals[key].indexOf(color)>-1){
        result.push(key)
      }
   });
  return result;

}

console.log(findColor(animals, "red"));
```